# Построение единого запроса MYSQL для удаления всех символов, кроме цифр и букв в WordPress

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения, wordpress

Друзья, помогите разобраться.
При включении кеша на wordpress, адрес типа:
`mydomain.com/?p=123` превратился в `mydomain.com/Hello-World`
Но вот ведь не задача, есть такие ссылки как:

```
mydomain.com/Hello.-World
mydomain.com/Hello-&-World
```

при их вводе, сайт выдаёт ошибку.
если удалить все лишние символы типа "." или "&", то всё ок и странички загружаются без проблем

для удаления я искользовал следующий такой запрос:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_name` = REPLACE( post_name, '.', '' );
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_name` = REPLACE( post_name, '&', '' );
```

И вот вопрос: как построить запрос так, чтобы удалились все символы, кроме

`БУКВ,ЦИФР и ТИРЕ` 
(одним запросом сразу) ?

Чтоб не строить 50 запросов на удаление.

Спасибо.

Comment: К сожалению, MySQL не умеет делать `replace` по `regexp`. Самый простой, на мой взгляд, способ - снять дамп базы, в нём удалить лишние символы и перезалить обратно. Либо удалять символы отдельными запросами.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, так и сделаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create procedure multiremove(charstodelete text) 
begin
while length(charstodelete)>0 do
    begin
    set @onechar = substring(charstodelete,1,1);
    set charstodelete = substring(charstodelete,2,length(charstodelete));
    set @sql=CONCAT("update wp_posts set post_name=replace(post_name,\'",@onechar,"\',\'\');");
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
    set @sql='';
    set @onechar='';
    end;
end while;
end;
```

На sql.ru - подробнее.

При желании можно доработать и передавать процедуре имя таблицы и поля.